# git rebase --interactive shows only the latest two commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

When running

```
git rebase --interactive
```

it only shows the latest two commits.
Why does this happen?

Current branch is `master`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used without explicit base specification `git rebase -i` rebases all commits that are newer than the last commit in upstream. In order to rebase more commits you need to explicitly specify the revision. For example: `git rebase -i HEAD~5` to rebase 5 last commits.